# columnFilter plugin not working with Angular DataTables Server Side Processing

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using Angular datatables (https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables) with server side processing, everything works fine if I didn't add the column filter But once I add the `withColumnFilter` option then search, pagination and records per page stop working.

Here is my HTML part:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<table datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Email ID</th>
  <th>Phone Number</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

JS Part:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('com.module.users')
.controller('UserCtrl', UserCtrl);

UserCtrl.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope', 'ENV', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder'];
function UserCtrl($state, $rootScope, ENV, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
var vm = this;

vm.currentPageState = $state.current.stateDesc;

vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('ajax', {
    url: ENV.apiUrl + vm.currentPageState.rUrl + '/users',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.globals.currentAdmin.token
    }
  })
  .withDataProp('data')
  .withOption('processing', true)
  .withOption('serverSide', true)
  .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
  .withBootstrap()
  .withColumnFilter({
    aoColumns: [{
      type: 'text',
      bRegex: true,
      bSmart: true
    }, {
      type: 'text',
      bRegex: true,
      bSmart: true
    }, {
      type: 'text',
      bRegex: true,
      bSmart: true
    }, {
      type: 'text',
      bRegex: true,
      bSmart: true
    }]
  });

vm.dtColumns = [
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email').withTitle('Email ID'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('phone').withTitle('Phone Number')
];
}

})();
```

After debugging what I found is ajax URL getting change to DOM URL. I have attached a screenshot for this:

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: Please provide details of your code. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ... and please don't mark questions as urgent. It may be urgent to you, but to readers both now and a year down the line, it isn't urgent at all.

Comment: See https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/475.

Comment: Hi l-lin, I have checked the issue #475 where you referenced the issue to #467 but does not worked out it seems jQuery column filter does not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using withFnServerData instead of ajax option.